# Game-Center Real-Time-Multiplayer, Reliable of Sandbox / Sync-State and how to test

Tags: objective-c, xcode, game-center, appstore-sandbox

Objective-C, Game-Center, App-Development in Xcode

My App features Game-Center Multiplayer with up to four players. Recently, it was approved by Apple and is avaiable on the App-Store.

Now, some players are complaining about getting out of sync while playing multiplayer, so the game doesnt show up with the same state on every player's device.

Probably, this seems to happen more often with three or four players than with only two players... And on the "real" Game-Center, I experienced this as well, and stucked in games with random opponents while playing my Live-Version of my App.

Alright, even I tested well, i opened a new Dev-Branch to start working on the new version. As soon as I install this new Branch on any device, I'm again authenticating and playing on Game-Center's Sandbox.

So - that leads me to my question: I play and play and play with three or four devices on the sandbox, and this "Out-Of-Sync-State" never happens - and I played  a lot of games now! And: It's extremly more faster, more smoothly, and almost realtime; in the Live-Version, I always have sync-times and lags, and the full experience is not that quick. But - that's not the problem - the problem is the huge difference between Sandbox and real Game-Center!

So - i guess somewhere is a inconsistency in my code that leads to this error. And: I really want to fix it, so that this can no more happen. But: How should I fix it, if I'm not able to reproduce it with activated Debug-Logs, because as soon as I activate them, I'm in the funny Sandbox where everything ist working much faster, more smoothly and never gets out of sync?

So, in detail the questions i came up:

- Is there a possibility, to activate Debug-Logs in XCode, compile on the device and play against the real Game-Center nevertheless??
- Did someone have a similar experience writting his Multiplayer-Code after Releasing the App on the App-Store?
- Does anyone have a different idea how I could find and catch this error, which has to be somewhere in my code or logic?

Comment: One little advice: I assume you have a run-loop, so you could try to build in some "artificial lag" in it. The run loop could then randomly get some extra milli seconds (you could also build in a lag-controller, which controlls the extra-lag ranges).

Comment: Thanks for your tip - artificial lags could be a good indicator. I just tried this way, not by adding code but just disable WLan and 3G on the test devices, even using different Mobile-Networks. It lagged as hell, but it fell back into synchronization as it should (waiting for all players to receive the needed data) ... strange. Using different iOS-Versions and 3 device-generations as test-devices, but of course, still playing in sandbox. Hmm... I'm kind of clueless.